# spring-boot hangs a while during start

Tags: spring-boot, raspberry-pi, apache-camel

One of our spring-boot applications using camel hangs on start for anywhere between 1 to 5 minutes, but not consistently.

The production environment the application runs in is the raspberry pi, running openJDK. We are unable to reproduce the issue on development machines.

Even on the pis however, the issue is exceedingly rare and seems to happen only on some. In fact we currently only have one in the field where this is a consistent problem, but there it's somewhat of a critical issue due to it being solar powered. The problem has been observed once before on another Pi, where it wasn't critical, and not 100% consistent, and went away again after a while.
Unfortunately we cannot test the pi for hardware issues. Travelling costs would be significant, so before we have no other option left we cannot afford to go and replace it with the possibility that not even that will fix the issue. Also, the pis syslog shows no suspicious activity at all during and around the time the hang happens.

This just to explain why I am posting the question even though a hardware issue cannot be 100% excluded at the moment. We simply need to exclude everything else first.

Now for the actual question: Here is a complete trace (log.level.root = TRACE) of the application at the time the hang occurs. I can provide a complete trace of the startup, but didn't think spamming thousands of lines of logs would help much.I am mostly interested in whether you see anything suspicious. I have looked at these entries for some time and cannot see any hint to the cause of the hang, but my experience with the inner life of spring-boot is very limited.

```
2019-10-30 08:28:16.090 DEBUG 456 --- [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory : Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2019-10-30 08:28:16.091 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Getting BeanInfo for class [org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.106 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Caching PropertyDescriptors for class [org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.107 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'applicationContext' of type [org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.107 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'beanFactory' of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.107 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'beanName' of type [java.lang.String]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.107 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'class' of type [java.lang.Class]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.108 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'embeddedValueResolver' of type [org.springframework.util.StringValueResolver]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.109 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'order' of type [int]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.109 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'scheduledTasks' of type [java.util.Set]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.109 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'scheduler' of type [java.lang.Object]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.185 DEBUG 456 --- [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory : Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor'
2019-10-30 08:28:16.186 DEBUG 456 --- [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor'
2019-10-30 08:28:16.186 DEBUG 456 --- [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory : Creating instance of bean 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor'
2019-10-30 08:28:16.370 DEBUG 456 --- [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'environment'
2019-10-30 08:28:16.375 DEBUG 456 --- [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory : Autowiring by type from bean name 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' via factory method to bean named 'environment'
2019-10-30 08:28:16.379 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver : Searching for key 'spring.aop.proxy-target-class' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties'
2019-10-30 08:28:16.381 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver : Searching for key 'spring.aop.proxy-target-class' in PropertySource 'commandLineArgs'
2019-10-30 08:28:16.381 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver : Searching for key 'spring.aop.proxy-target-class' in PropertySource 'systemProperties'
2019-10-30 08:28:16.381 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver : Searching for key 'spring.aop.proxy-target-class' in PropertySource 'systemEnvironment'
2019-10-30 08:28:16.381 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver : Searching for key 'spring.aop.proxy-target-class' in PropertySource 'random'
2019-10-30 08:28:16.381 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver : Searching for key 'spring.aop.proxy-target-class' in PropertySource 'applicationConfig: [file:./application.properties]'
2019-10-30 08:28:16.381 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver : Searching for key 'spring.aop.proxy-target-class' in PropertySource 'applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]'
2019-10-30 08:28:16.381 DEBUG 456 --- [main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver : Could not find key 'spring.aop.proxy-target-class' in any property source
2019-10-30 08:28:16.398 DEBUG 456 --- [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory : Eagerly caching bean 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2019-10-30 08:28:16.399 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Getting BeanInfo for class [org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.437 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Caching PropertyDescriptors for class [org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.437 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'beanClassLoader' of type [java.lang.ClassLoader]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.437 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'beanFactory' of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.437 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'beforeExistingAdvisors' of type [boolean]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.438 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'class' of type [java.lang.Class]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.438 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'exposeProxy' of type [boolean]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.439 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'frozen' of type [boolean]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.440 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'opaque' of type [boolean]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.440 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'optimize' of type [boolean]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.441 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'order' of type [int]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.441 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'proxyClassLoader' of type [java.lang.ClassLoader]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.441 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'proxyTargetClass' of type [boolean]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.442 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'repositoryAnnotationType' of type [java.lang.Class]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.507 DEBUG 456 --- [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory : Finished creating instance of bean 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor'
2019-10-30 08:28:16.507 DEBUG 456 --- [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'dataSourceInitializerPostProcessor'
2019-10-30 08:28:16.507 DEBUG 456 --- [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory : Creating instance of bean 'dataSourceInitializerPostProcessor'
2019-10-30 08:28:16.522 DEBUG 456 --- [main] o.s.b.f.annotation.InjectionMetadata : Registered injected element on class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor]: AutowiredFieldElement for private org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.beanFactory
2019-10-30 08:28:16.522 DEBUG 456 --- [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory : Eagerly caching bean 'dataSourceInitializerPostProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2019-10-30 08:28:16.522 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Getting BeanInfo for class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.532 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Caching PropertyDescriptors for class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.533 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'class' of type [java.lang.Class]
2019-10-30 08:28:16.533 TRACE 456 --- [main] o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults : Found bean property 'order' of type [int]

// Note the significant time jump!

2019-10-30 08:30:16.087 TRACE 454 --- [main] org.apache.sshd.client.SshClient : addSessionListener(SshClient[f66866])[org.apache.sshd.common.session.helpers.SessionTimeoutListener@b50150] registered
2019-10-30 08:30:16.088 TRACE 454 --- [main] .a.s.c.u.t.ThreadUtils$SshdThreadFactory : newThread(java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10])[sshd-SshClient[f66866]-timer-thread-1] runnable=java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@1b986cd[State = -1, empty queue]
2019-10-30 08:30:16.161 TRACE 454 --- [main] o.a.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Connector : Creating Nio2Connector
2019-10-30 08:30:16.162 DEBUG 454 --- [main] o.a.camel.component.ssh.SshProducer : Starting producer: Producer[ssh://root:xxxxxx@192.168.1.1]
2019-10-30 08:30:16.162 TRACE 454 --- [main] org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport : Starting service
2019-10-30 08:30:16.162 DEBUG 454 --- [main] o.a.camel.component.exec.ExecProducer : Starting producer: Producer[exec://sudo]
2019-10-30 08:30:16.162 TRACE 454 --- [main] org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport : Starting service
2019-10-30 08:30:16.162 DEBUG 454 --- [main] o.a.camel.component.exec.ExecProducer : Starting producer: Producer[exec://sudo]
2019-10-30 08:30:16.162 TRACE 454 --- [main] org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport : Starting service
2019-10-30 08:30:16.162 DEBUG 454 --- [main] o.a.c.c.direct.DirectBlockingProducer : Starting producer: Producer[direct://switch-off-camera]
2019-10-30 08:30:16.162 TRACE 454 --- [main] org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport : Starting service
2019-10-30 08:30:16.163 DEBUG 454 --- [main] o.a.camel.component.seda.SedaProducer : Starting producer: Producer[seda://capture-image]
2019-10-30 08:30:16.163 TRACE 454 --- [main] org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport : Starting service
2019-10-30 08:30:16.163 DEBUG 454 --- [main] o.a.c.c.direct.DirectBlockingProducer : Starting producer: Producer[direct://switch-off-camera]
2019-10-30 08:30:16.163 TRACE 454 --- [main] org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport : Starting service
2019-10-30 08:30:16.163 DEBUG 454 --- [main] o.a.camel.component.seda.SedaProducer : Starting producer: Producer[seda://image-queue]
2019-10-30 08:30:16.163 TRACE 454 --- [main] org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport : Starting service
2019-10-30 08:30:16.163 DEBUG 454 --- [main] o.a.c.c.direct.DirectBlockingProducer : Starting producer: Producer[direct://failed-upload]
2019-10-30 08:30:16.163 TRACE 454 --- [main] org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport : Starting service
2019-10-30 08:30:16.163 DEBUG 454 --- [main] o.a.c.c.direct.DirectBlockingProducer : Starting producer: Producer[direct://switch-off-camera]
2019-10-30 08:30:16.163 TRACE 454 --- [main] org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport : Starting service
2019-10-30 08:30:16.164 TRACE 454 --- [main] org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport : Starting service
2019-10-30 08:30:16.164 DEBUG 454 --- [main] o.a.camel.component.seda.SedaProducer : Starting producer: Producer[seda://capture-command]
2019-10-30 08:30:16.164 DEBUG 454 --- [main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext : Route: route1 >>> EventDrivenConsumerRoute[seda://start-deepsleep -> Pipeline[[Channel[Log(route1)[Starting deep sleep for ${body} seconds]], Channel[SetBody(Simple: sh -c '(sleep 15; io set out0 1; sleep 2; lpm -i ${body})' </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &)], Channel[Log(route1)[Executing SSH command: ${body}]], C
2019-10-30 08:30:16.165 DEBUG 454 --- [main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext : Starting consumer (order: 1000) on route: route1
2019-10-30 08:30:16.165 TRACE 454 --- [main] a.c.m.DefaultManagementLifecycleStrategy : Checking whether to register SedaConsumer[seda://start-deepsleep] from route: EventDrivenConsumerRoute[seda://start-deepsleep -> Pipeline[[Channel[Log(route1)[Starting deep sleep for ${body} seconds]], Channel[SetBody(Simple: sh -c '(sleep 15; io set out0 1; sleep 2; lpm -i ${body})' </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1
2019-10-30 08:30:16.166 DEBUG 454 --- [main] javax.management.mbeanserver : name = org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=consumers,name=SedaConsumer(0x1f22f18)
2019-10-30 08:30:16.167 DEBUG 454 --- [main] javax.management.mbeanserver : name = org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=consumers,name=SedaConsumer(0x1f22f18)
2019-10-30 08:30:16.167 TRACE 454 --- [main] o.a.c.management.DefaultManagementAgent : Registering MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=consumers,name=SedaConsumer(0x1f22f18)
2019-10-30 08:30:16.168 TRACE 454 --- [main] o.a.c.m.DefaultManagementMBeanAssembler : Assembling MBeanInfo for: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=consumers,name=SedaConsumer(0x1f22f18) from @ManagedResource object: org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedConsumer@8572f0
2019-10-30 08:30:16.168 TRACE 454 --- [main] o.a.camel.management.MBeanInfoAssembler : Extracting attributes and operations from class: class org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedConsumer
2019-10-30 08:30:16.174 TRACE 454 --- [main] o.a.camel.management.MBeanInfoAssembler : Extracting attributes and operations from method: public java.lang.Integer org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedConsumer.getInflightExchanges()
2019-10-30 08:30:16.175 TRACE 454 --- [main] o.a.camel.management.MBeanInfoAssembler : Extracting attributes and operations from method: public org.apache.camel.Consumer org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedConsumer.getConsumer()
2019-10-30 08:30:16.175 TRACE 454 --- [main] o.a.camel.management.MBeanInfoAssembler : Extracting attributes and operations from method: public java.lang.String org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedConsumer.getEndpointUri()
2019-10-30 08:30:16.175 TRACE 454 --- [main] o.a.camel.management.MBeanInfoAssembler : Extracting attributes and operations from sub class: class org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedService
2019-10-30 08:30:16.176 TRACE 454 --- [main] o.a.camel.management.MBeanInfoAssembler : Extracting attributes and operations from class: class org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedService
2019-10-30 08:30:16.180 TRACE 454 --- [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] org.apache.camel.util.LRUCache : onRemoval class org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedService -> null
2019-10-30 08:30:16.180 TRACE 454 --- [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] org.apache.camel.util.LRUCache : onRemoval interface org.apache.camel.api.management.mbean.ManagedServiceMBean -> null
2019-10-30 08:30:16.180 TRACE 454 --- [main] o.a.camel.management.MBeanInfoAssembler : Extracting attributes and operations from method: public java.lang.String org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedService.getServiceType()
2019-10-30 08:30:16.180 TRACE 454 --- [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] org.apache.camel.util.LRUCache : onRemoval class org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedProducer -> null
2019-10-30 08:30:16.181 TRACE 454 --- [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] org.apache.camel.util.LRUCache : onRemoval interface org.apache.camel.api.management.mbean.ManagedProducerMBean -> null
2019-10-30 08:30:16.181 TRACE 454 --- [main] o.a.camel.management.MBeanInfoAssembler : Extracting attributes and operations from method: public boolean org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedService.isSupportSuspension()
2019-10-30 08:30:16.182 TRACE 454 --- [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] org.apache.camel.util.LRUCache : onRemoval interface org.apache.camel.api.management.ManagedInstance -> null
2019-10-30 08:30:16.182 TRACE 454 --- [main] o.a.camel.management.MBeanInfoAssembler : Extracting attributes and operations from method: public boolean org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedService.isStaticService()
2019-10-30 08:30:16.182 TRACE 454 --- [main] o.a.camel.management.MBeanInfoAssembler : Extracting attributes and operations from method: public void org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedService.setRoute(org.apache.camel.Route)
2019-10-30 08:30:16.182 TRACE 454 --- [main] o.a.camel.management.MBeanInfoAssembler : Extracting attributes and operations from method: public java.lang.String org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedService.getCamelManagementName()
```

I've marked the gap in time where nothing appears to be happening. Now, there are a few entries in there that I've taken out. The quartz job-store is doing its thing with the h2 database, and a scheduled task by one of our services is already already running. No suspicious things, and we managed to exclude them entirely in some test runs, but it shows that the system as a whole isn't stalled. Spring-boot just seems to be waiting for *something* before continuing.

I was hoping that somebody more at home with spring-boot might tell me what spring-boot is waiting for in that time based on these logs.

We have also excluded the possibility of wrong logging times (i.e. that the hang isn't actually there, instead the clock jumps), especially since this is a pi.

It may or may not be noteworthy that the hang occurs between camel instantiating the endpoints and camel starting the routes. Usually these are only a second appart, but I'd expect to see some sings of trouble in the log if there would be a hang-up with that.

Comment: If have a hunch, this might not be the solution but I wanted to share it nonetheless: I assume there are not many services running on the Pi you are deploying to. This might be an issue: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13209_01/wlcp/wlss30/configwlss/jvmrand.html

Comment: Oh my god, you hit it in the first go! This is it, it works now! Thanks a lot, you saved us a world of trouble!

Comment: That was a lucky guess ;). I had a similiar issue on a deployment server which had no noise and Tomcat startup was dreadfully slow. I will copy write a proper answer for completeness sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the Pi you are deploying to does not have enough "noise" for the random number generator to start properly. Oracle has a solution for this issue: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13209_01/wlcp/wlss30/configwlss/jvmrand.html